# Filtering a form

Tags: vba, ms-access, ms-access-forms

I have a form that is fed with a query and depends on a single table, the query looks like this:

```
SELECT Documentación.Fecha, Documentación.Categoría, Documentación.Médico, Documentación.Paciente, Documentación.Fichero, Documentación.Fichero.FileName, Documentación.Papel
FROM Pacientes RIGHT JOIN (Médicos RIGHT JOIN (Categorías RIGHT JOIN Documentación ON Categorías.Id = Documentación.Categoría) ON Médicos.Id = Documentación.Médico) ON Pacientes.Id = Documentación.Paciente
ORDER BY Documentación.Fecha;
```

In the table and in the form, there is a field that contains appended files.

What I need is the code to filter the records of the form based on the record, whether or not it has an appended file, so what we are needing is invoke the filter method of the form with a sentence, but which is the sentence? I tryed these ones:

`Me.Filter = [Fichero].AttachmentCount = 0`

where "Fichero" is the field name which cotains the file attached

But I'm afraid this one doesn't work

Comment: Are you aware that embedding files in table uses up Access 2GB size limit? This would be simple if you only saved a filepath in text field. See Gord Thompson answer in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21106241/how-can-i-check-if-an-attachment-field-is-empty-or-not-in-access

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I check if an attachment field is empty or not in Access?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21106241/how-can-i-check-if-an-attachment-field-is-empty-or-not-in-access)

Comment: Yes, I think I'm doing some things in a bad way, it's an error store files on a Db with this  limit. In this case, the size of the all files should be less than the limit, but, but, but you never know. So you are right